# How to overwrite RabbitMQ user and password (k8s)?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

Friends,

I am running a RabbitMQ container in K8S. When I ran it for the first time I created a simple password and a username, which I want to change now but I just can't somehow. I've changed the values here but they aren't being overwritten:

```
  env:
        - name: "RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER"
          value: "Z3Vlc3Q="  
        - name: "RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS"
          value: "Z3Vlc3Q="
```

When I open the UI I still have to log in with the old credentials. Any idea how can I update them?

Comment: Did you redeploy after the change?

Comment: Yes I did. I deleted all the resources and deployed them again.

Comment: Maybe remove the double quotes and try?

Comment: I have just tried. Still no success.

Comment: Assuming that your `RabbitMQ` is deployed with some kind of `Volume` to store the data across rescheduling etc., maybe it's storing the credentials you used for the first time?

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks a lot.